# Distribution fitting on empirical PDF?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, density-function, curve-fitting

I have a class of distributions that I think may have generated some data I have, and would like to find the best fit distribution and corresponding parameters. But the data I have aren't samples from a distribution, they are an empirical PDF.

Comment: Do you think you could provide a little more insight into what your data looks like.  I am a little confused.

Comment: Sure, the data is of the form: $(x,P(X=x))$ for $x \in [1,1000]$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, for every value of $x\in[1,1000]$ you have an associated probability?  Also, is $x\in\mathbb{N}$ or is $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, and $x\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: BTW, I can always generate samples from the PDF I have and use the classical distribution fitting techniques on those -- I was just wondering if anyone on here knows a more principled way.

Comment: (1) How do you know the probabilities for each $x$? How are they measured or estimated? (2) It is hard to make sense of this question using conventional meanings of "distribution" and "PDF," because it literally says you have data from a distribution and you do not. Perhaps you could be more specific about how you obtain your data?

Comment: Wouldn't the information from which you get the empirical pdf be the data? (That is, the data should be constructable from the original $n$ and your $\hat p_i$s). Since you're talking about a discrete distribution, you shouldn't really talk about density ('pdf').

Comment: @user30371, clearly a lot of people are confused about your question.  I wonder if the confusion stems from you using the word "data" when that is not what you mean.  Given that you have actual probabilities, it sounds like what you have is not data, but rather a probability mass function, given as a list of probabilities, and your task is to find the formula for generating those probabilities.  Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more clear. I have a histogram of empirical counts for every $x\in[1,1000],x\in\mathbb{N}$. I converted these into probabilities by simply normalizing by the total number of counts. I'd like to find the best-fit theoretical PMF (from my hypothesized class of distributions) that most closely approximates my data.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have some knowledge on how the empirical PDF was obtained ?
Like if it was obtained from an histogram with entries / bin, then you can perform a max likelihood fit or a least square fit of your class of distributions directly on the histogram data.
The fit setup depends on your histogram:

- if bins have small counts (like < 20 entries), it is better to describe each bin by a Poisson (when N is not fixed) or a multinomial (when N is fixed) PDF and then perform a maximum likelihood fit.
- if bins have large counts, then you can approximate the PDF of each bin as a normal distribution and perform a least square fit with sqrt(entries) as bin uncertainty. The advantage of this approach is that you can quantify the goodness-of-fit via the resulting chi2Min after fit.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vectorof values and probabilities, one simple way to fit a distribution is to create a "theoretical" vector along side the empirical one, and use a non-linear solver (`SOLVER` in Excel if the distribution has `2` or fewer parameters, `nloptr` or `optim` or `nlminb` in `R`, etc.) to minimize the sum of squared differences between the empirical and the test vector.